# Python CSV how to iterate through a list

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

f =open('Scores.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    #next(readCSV)

users = []
quizzes = []
grades = []

for row in csv_f:

    user = row[0]
    quiz = row[2]
    grade = row[5]

    users.append(user)
    quizzes.append(quiz)
    grades.append(grade)

whatUser = input ("User: ")

if whatUser in users:
    coldex = users.index(whatUser)
    theQuiz = quizzes[coldex]
    theGrade = grades[coldex]

    print("Username: ", whatUser)
    print("Quizzes: ", theQuiz)
    print("Grades: ", theGrade)
```

I'm trying to get this program to look for all of the users in row[0] and then print the relevant information on rows[2] and [5]. As you can see in the attached image it only finds 1 Bob and not the second when the code is run.

[Used file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzWdk.png)

Comment: Don't attach images when you want to show text. That's unnecessarily hard for us to read. But that aside, hi! So, you forgot to ask a question, and you also don't show what you've tried so far to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last part to:

```
for i in range(len(users)):
    if users[i] == whatUser:
        theQuiz = quizzes[i]
        theGrade = grades[i]

        print("Username: ", whatUser)
        print("Quizzes: ", theQuiz)
        print("Grades: ", theGrade)
```

`index(x)` will only return the first index of element `x`. Hence, you have to loop and handle all matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the users and print each one that matches:

```
for i, user in enumerate(users):
    if user == whatUser:
        print("Username: ", whatUser)
        print("Quizzes: ", quizzes[i])
        print("Grades: ", grades[i])
```